# Google Apps Script — Automatically Email and Share

Tags: google-apps-script

I am attempting to write a small Google Apps script that will send a confirmation email and automatically share a folder with a logged-in user after they complete a form. Here is the script:

```csh
function formSubmitReply(e) {
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(),
    subject: "Keuka College Brand Download Center",
    htmlBody: 
              "<p>Thank you for requesting access to the Keuka College Brand Download Center. Your access has been approved.</p>" +
              "<p>You may access the download center by <a href='https://drive.google.com/a/keuka.edu/folderview?id=0B856ZeGoaGT_MG5BMEtEVGwzYkk&usp=sharing'>using this link,</a> " +
              "visiting <a href='http://brand.keuka.edu'>Keuka College Brand Central,</a> or through your Google Drive.</p><p>Please contact the Office of Marketing and Communications " +
              "with any questions you may have.</p>",
    name: "Keuka College",
    replyTo: "marketing@keuka.edu"
  });

 var folder = DocsList.getFolder('Brand Download Center');
 folder.addViewer(Session.getActiveUser());

}​
```

This seems to be working, except it keeps emailing it to me -- not the user who is completing the form. I am not sure if it is sharing correctly.

Could someone provide some insight? This is my first time working with Google Apps script.

Answer (score 0):

`Session.getActiveUser()` is the user that uses the form editor and the user that created the trigger that calls this function.

What you want us the user that filled the form.

Look at the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response) to see how you can retrieve that value. Note that it will [only be available if you are in a domain](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#setCollectEmail(Boolean)).

---

**EDIT** (*sorry for the delay*)

Here is a sample code to show how to get the form respondent in formApp (works only in GAFE or GA Business)

It will send you a mail with the name of the last form submitter (don't forget to create an installable onEdit trigger to test this).

```
function onSubmit(){
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var formResponses = form.getResponses();
  var lastResponse = formResponses[formResponses.length-1];
  var user = lastResponse.getRespondentEmail()
  var userString = 'user = '+user;
  MailApp.sendEmail(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(),'form submission report',userString);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I have changed it as follows, but it still doesn't seem to be working. Any suggestions? (Partial Code): function formSubmitReply(e) {
  
  var email = e.getRespondentEmail();
  
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: email,

Comment: And are you using a business or edu account?

Comment: Did you check the option to retrieve the form submitter email?  I'd should appear clearly in the form itself when a user opens the online form.

Comment: Am I not using the right object on getRespondentEmail? I have it hooked up as a trigger, so I'm thinking I can use e., but I might be misunderstanding. This is my first Google Apps script.

Comment: Yes - it is collecting the email information, and it's storing it in the spreadsheet.

Comment: I have to leave now, sorry...but will be back in a couple of hours :-)